# How does URL Encoding work?

Tags: url, encoding

I am learning about web security, but I'm very confused about URL Encoding.

On PortSwigger, I learned that the URL `http://127.0.0.1/admin`
can be written as `http://127.0.0.1/%2561dmin`
by encoding `a` as  `%61` and then encoding `%` again, thus making it `%2561`

When I try this on my local computer, single URL encoding works.
`http://127.0.0.1/%61dmin` is interpreted as `http://127.0.0.1/admin`

But double URL encoding does not work. `http://127.0.0.1/%2561dmin` becomes `http://127.0.0.1/%61dmin`

I am confused about how server knows how many times it has to decode the URL. And is this always the case or it will only works in some cases (as it didn't work on my localhost and some other places I've tried)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I am confused about how server knows how many time it have to decode URL

Always only once. And this is true for other encodings too, i.e. binary data in mails are encoded **once** with base64 or quoted-printable, unicode is encoded **once** with utf-8, HTML encoding is applied **once** for characters like `<` etc in HTML etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering but as taught in this lab "https://portswigger.net/web-security/ssrf/lab-ssrf-with-blacklist-filter", I needed to use double-URL encoding  for bypass filters.

Comment: I find answer https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185455/when-and-why-does-bypassing-xss-sanitizers-with-double-encoding-work which explains why double url encoding worked in above case.

Comment: @Anni: yes, there might be a difference between how often the server should decode a URL vs. how often this is actually done due to errors, i.e. *"...different parts of the applicaition makes different assumptions about if a variable is encoded or not..."*.